# Difference between python's sched.scheduler and threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to schedule a function to run at a later point in time in python. Googling gave me 2 set of solutions to achieve it. One set of solutions recommended python's sched.scheduler and others were recommending threading.Timer.

1. What's the difference between them ?
2. Which one should I use ?

Comment: what is your specific use case? Either (or other option to delay a call) can be used in different circumstances.

Comment: Timer seems better, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036348/to-execute-a-function-every-x-minutes-sched-or-threading-timer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To execute a function every x minutes: sched or threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036348/to-execute-a-function-every-x-minutes-sched-or-threading-timer)