# To execute a function every x minutes: sched or threading.Timer?

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I need to program the execution of a give method every x minutes.

I found two ways to do it: the first is using the `sched` module, and the second is using `Threading.Timer`.

**First method**:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # do your stuff
    sc.enter(60, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

**The second**:

```
import threading

def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # do your stuff
   t = threading.Timer(0.5,do_something).start()

do_something(sc)
```

What's the difference and if there is one better than the other, which one?

Comment: I think this can also be done by `asyncio`, but I'm not good (yet) with that module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not safe in Python 2 - Python 3.2:

From [the Python 2.7 **`sched`** documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html):

> In multi-threaded environments, the [`scheduler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler) class has limitations with respect to thread-safety, inability to insert a new task before the one currently pending in a running scheduler, and holding up the main thread until the event queue is empty. Instead, the preferred approach is to use the [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) class instead.

From [the latest Python 3 **`sched`** documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

> *Changed in version 3.3:* [`scheduler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler) class can be safely used in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: Python 3.3 implementation of `sched` claims to be thread-safe in a multiprocessing environment. Perhaps edit you should edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: What is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: @VivekSubramanian I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps it would be best to search and ask a new question if you don't find anything.